# syslog-ng how to use nested filters?

Tags: filtering, sendmail, syslog-ng

I'd like to use syslog-ng to do nested filtering of messages from sendmail. I think its called nested filtering. I don't know much about the intricacies of pattern matching and filtering in syslog-ng, I apologize.

I need to find a message that matches an IP address, then save the QID in that same message. Using that QID, I want to then capture all messages from the 'sm-mta' process that are for that specific QID. These messages don't always include that IP address, which makes this problem seem tricky to me.

Example:

```
Mar 28 22:58:22 mail-server.com sm-mta[18687]: 02SMwLVG018687: from=<someone@somewhere.com>, size=1581, class=0, nrcpts=7, msgid=<user@ip>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, tls_verify=NONE, auth=NONE, relay=source-server.com [3.3.3.3]
```

Look for `relay=`, and then match on `3.3.3.3`. Save the `02SMwLVG018687` QID, then capture and send all messages that have that QID to a specific destination.

Can this be handled? Maybe I need post processing outside of syslog-ng?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/364685/what-command-can-i-use-to-search-sendmail-logs-for-all-message-details-involving Looks like he's asking about similar nested matching, but the method he is requesting to solve it is outside of syslogging.

Comment: I think it's possible inside syslog-ng. This message can be parsed easily with kv-parser(), you can filter messages based on the relay field then. You can also match patterns using the PatternDB module. The "redirect all messages that have that QID elsewhere" is not clear for me, can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm just saying that after the match with the IP address, then send all messages with that associated QID to a specific destination. Apologies, "redirect" is a bit ambiguous.